# What is the difference between Computer Science and Software Engineering?

Tags: computer-science

I was spurred to ask the question by an answer I saw for a question on [Software Engineering Videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853514/where-can-i-find-video-lectures-on-software-engineering).  Here's the answer:

> As an aside, be careful what you're linking here. Software Engineering
>   and Computer Science are very different disciplines. Software
>   Engineering encompasses the software development lifecycle (including
>   methodologies and process), modeling, communication, enterprise SE
>   culture, etc. and is much, much less concerned with code, algorithms,
>   efficiency, and the like.
>
> *Answered on May 12 by JoshJordan*

and this was my comment:

> I have to disagree somewhat. Software Engineering is a sub-discipline
>   of Computer Science. One of the sub-areas of Software Engineering is
>   Construction, which is all about code. Please refer to [SWEBOK](http://www.swebok.org/).

I do think algorithms fall outside of Software Engineering, but object-oriented programming, secure programming, and the like do not.

Some have said this is a duplicate, but Computer Engineering is about the hardware and Software Engineering is about the software.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384164/computer-engineering-vs-computer-science

Comment: computer engineering is NOT software engineering
computer engineering is about making hardware ... a mix of computer science and ELECTRICAL engineering

Comment: What is your question? It appears you've simply posted an opinion here. Post your opinion in the original question. This question should be closed on the basis of "Not a question" and "Duplicate".

Comment: @LWoodyiii: While that is true in some countries, keep in mind that in other ones, the equivalent of Computer Science is called Computer Engineering

Comment: Very interesting.  Which countries?

Comment: How can you say algorithms fall outside of software engineering?  Algorithms are a finite series of instructions used to solve a problem.  Code.

Comment: @LWoodyiii: As far as I know, in spanish speaking countries, for example.

Answer (score 21):

In the most reductionist and simplistic of terms: **computer science is theory, and software engineering is practice**. This is similar to the relationship between, for example, chemistry (bonds, valence shells, the periodic table, quantum theory) and chemical engineering (industrial production, purity yield, finding the best material given a set of constraints).

Comment: Good insight, but personally I would say Software Engineering sits in an even higher level than chemical engineering compared to chemistry. Or, say, electronics compared to solid state physics. Software Engineering concerns problems such as "how many chemical engineers you need to replace a lamp?"

Answer (score 12):

I just read an article via /. about this very topic:
[Software Engineering ≠ Computer Science](http://www.ddj.com/architect/217701907)

This image from the article sums it up nicely:
[image: Red line separating computer science and software engineering]

Answer (score 8):

As great computer science [Dijkstra](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/computer_science_is_no_more_about_computers_than/334131.html) famously said, "Computer science is no more about computers than astronomy is about telescopes.”.  So, saying that software engineering (which does have to do with computers) is a sub-discipline of computer science, is like saying which optics (which does have to do with telescopes) is a sub-discipline of astronomy;-).

Me, I care about telescopes, oops I mean computers, so clearly I'm not an astronomer, oops I mean a computer scientist;-) [whatever [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Martelli) insists on saying about me;-)], exactly as I once wrote in [my blog](http://aleaxit.blogspot.com/2008_09_01_archive.html).

Comment: works fine for me -- by either clicking on it or copying and pasting it, http://aleaxit.blogspot.com/2008_09_01_archive.html -- what problems are you observing?

Comment: I don't think Dijkstra meant that at all. He is referring more to the relationship between CS and electronics, for example. And one might even say the opposite from what you said, that Software Engineering is the astronomy to the CS telescope.

Answer (score 3):

Computer Science is more theory than hands-on; Software Engineering is still theory, but more hands on; Computer Information Systems is more hands-on and less theory, and Management Information Systems is all hands-on with very little theory.

Answer (score 1):

For the spirit of stack overflow:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Engineering

Comment: Well, technically the spirit of SO is to copy relevant portions of linked sites into answers, in case linked sites go away ... 

Answer (score 0):

Well, all of these disciplines are just a subdisciplines of Phylosophy.

Comment: What is your perspective on this? The 'answer' as is, isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Computer Science : It covers the core concepts and technologies involved with how to make a computer do something. Learning to program a computer by writing software is essential, and computer programming is used in most computer science courses.

Software [Engineering](http://ggi.ac.in/) : SE is about designing and developing software. Techniques, technologies, good practices, testing, and so on. To make an example, your browser has been developed by Software Engineers.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Computer Science is the entire field of theory and application that involves doing computations on computers as well as encompassing how computers work. It is the complete science of computers.

Software engineering is a much smaller subset of Computer Science that just has to do with the theory, concepts, and applications of writing actual programs.

Computer Science refers to a lot more than just what goes into writing programs.